# Why is my design image deformed and moved? It seems to fit on the uv map layout, but not on the model itself, how should I fix it?

Tags: uv

I am only beginning with Blender and tried to create a coffee pouch while following some tutorials.

I thought I did everything the same, marked seams, unwrapped model, exported UV layout, made layout fitting design in adobe illustrator (only the front side yet to try how it fits) and then used shader editor, but the imported design seems to be deformed and moved on the side.

It will be probably some silly mistake I made along the way, but I can't figure out what I did wrong. How can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: I can't see from your image, but I think it has to do with the values in your _mapping_ node - either manually place the islands (as you have) _or_ "find and position" your texture through a mapping node - don't do both, its easy to confuse yourself and get lost.

Comment: Hi Lucie, welcome to Blender SE. It is normal, that you make mistakes when following tutorials. So either you restart again and follow each step exactly as in the tutorial, or you give us enough informations so that we can help you because you didn't show us enough information so that we can help you. Because you are a beginner i would suggest you provide your blend file so we can check it out what you have done. Just open https://blend-exchange.com/ and follow instructions.